# Нужна ли прописная буква?

Tags: орфография

«Под грифом "Секретно"» — слово *секретно* пишется с прописной или строчной буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это в зависимости как выглядит этот самый гриф. Зрительно — его обычно пишут заглавными. Но, кажется, встречается и написание "Секретно". Так что как вариант наверняка пройдёт.